# InvalidClassException when drawing a circle. Why?

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw

This is the first time that I draw something on android. I followed a tutorial on developers.android.com:

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

And obviously I should create a custom view and override `onDraw` and I can start drawing on the `Canvas` parameter! So I created a view like this:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
    private Canvas canvas;

    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public CanvasView (Context c) {
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas c) {
        canvas = c;
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor (Color.BLACK);
        c.drawCircle (50, 50, 25, p);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a method to get the canvas object. This is because I want to be able to add stuff to the view from other code (not in this class). I think my code makes sense. I just want to draw a black circle!

When I run the app, it crashed immediately with a `InvalidClassException`:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: dfa; Incompatible class (SUID): dfa: static final long serialVersionUID =8874316054258000122L; but expected dfa: static final long serialVersionUID =0L;
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2383)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
        at com.google.android.apps.plus.service.EsService.c(PG:5140)
        at com.google.android.apps.plus.service.EsService.b(PG:5064)
        at com.google.android.apps.plus.service.EsService.a(PG:2522)
        at com.google.android.apps.plus.service.EsService.c(PG:2613)
        at com.google.android.apps.plus.service.PackageAddedReceiver.onReceive(PG:37)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2488)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I searched for questions abount `InvalidClassException`s but I found nothing like this. They are all about deserialization stuff. I found the word `serialVersionUID` which is relevant to serialization inn the call stack but my code doesn't do anything with serialization!

I think it might be because of the `Canvas` field. If that is really the problem, is there any other way that I can draw stuff on the UI but without the use of drawable resource files? If this is not the problem, then what is? I don't know why a `InvalidClassException` has anything to do with drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the serialVersionUID, as it wasn't explicitly defined in the code, was autogenerated to 8874316054258000122L, which it was not what it was expected.

Try to manually set the serialVersionUID to 0L, as expected by `dfa`:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
```

Comment: When I run the second time, no exception is thrown! Can you explain this?

Comment: Mmm, I believe that it's automatically set to 0L, as expected by dfa, after the exception is thrown